# Three.js - showing shadows in multiple views

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

[In this example](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_multiple_views.html) of multiple views, shadows are implemented in quite a complicated way, rather than using the simpler way such as setting an object's property `castShadow = true`. Can shadows not be done that way with multiple views? I tried implementing shadows the simpler way for a multiple view, but they didn't show. Is 'manually' creating shadows the only way to do it for multiple views?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that conflicts will occur with multiple cameras when `renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true`. I have not see it tried, actually.

Your work-around would be to fake shadows, as was done in the example you referenced. Just use an image for your shadow.

three.js r.55